# How do I load a folder of images in automatically?

Tags: python, image, pygame

I have a folder named images that is in the directory of my program, and I would like my program to go through all of the images and load them automatically into my code as variables. For example:

> myProgramDirectory/images/cat.png
>
> myProgramDirectory/images/dog.png
>
> myProgramDirectory/images/banana.png

And then in the code I would have 3 variables for each image that is already loaded, like a cat, dog, and banana image variable.

Comment: Why do you need them as separate variables? How would you know if a variable exist?

Comment: For the separate variables, that's a given because if I were to load them in each individually, they would still be individual variables. And to check if a variable existed it would be as simple as checking the images folder.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can load each image in as an individual variable, but you can load them into a dictionary with each image attached to a key equal to the image name.

```
import os
import pygame

images = {str(i)[:-4]:pygame.image.load("images/"+i) for i in os.listdir("images") if os.path.isfile("images/"+i)}
```

Comment: If it all being only one line is too cramped for you, you can easily expand it a bit.